# Ofbiz POS(Point of Sale) cannot be started

Tags: ofbiz

I'm trying run Ofbiz POS and getting the following error. I'm using Ofbiz 13.xx.xx

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot load configuration properties : org/ofbiz
/base/start/-pos.properties
```

When I run

```
java -jar ofbiz.jar pos
```

The server was running and pos application was not started.
Do I need to install or build something more ?
Kindly help.

Comment: doc says `java -jar ofbiz.jar -pos` ?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

```
ant start-pos
```

Linux:

```
./ant start-pos
```

(inbuilt ant of OFBiz)

OR

```
ant start-pos
```

(if ant is installed in the linux)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
ant start -pos
```

in windows systems or

```
./ant start -pos
```

in Linux Systems

Tony John

Comment: Instead of telling the user to just try something, why not take the time to explain *why* they should try it? Right now, this is a pretty low quality answer.

Comment: java -jar ofbiz.jar -pos was working for older versions. From 12.xx.xx they started using new format.

Comment: Here is an excerpt of [the POS official documentation][1]

With  [OFBIZ-7804][2] The POS has been pushed in  OFBiz Attic.

The last released version with the POS available was R12.04.06. It's though still available in the R14.12 and 15.12 non released branches. It'll not be available with the R16 release and further. All the POS official documentationis reliable and usable before revision 1754402


  [1]: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System
  [2]: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-7804